# SQL query to display Male as “M” and Female as “F”

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

how to write SQL query to display Male as “M” and Female as “F” from below table:

```
TableA
Name    Gender
JOHN    Male
ANSARI  Female
BABILONA    Male
KEZCSEELO   Male
RAJINI  Male
LOSEC   Female
NHOJ    Female
```

Comment: Perhaps Left(Gender,1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Case` Statement

```
Select 
    Name,
    Case when Gender = 'Male' then 'M' when Gender = 'Female' then 'F' else 'Other' end
from TableA
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, since "M" and "F" are the first characters, you can just use SUBSTRING.

```
SELECT Name,
    SUBSTRING(Gender, 1,1)
FROM tableA
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is possibly some logic to handle if a value in the column is not Male or Female, although that was not part of the criteria. My favorite answer still.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select name
    , case when gender = 'Male' then 'M' when gender = 'Female' then 'F' else 'Unknown' end 
from tableA
```

Answer (score 0):

i cant comment so i'm posting a small update to a already given answer by John Pasquet. Shaulinator already noted that we dont know logic behind the gender column but i would still think you would want to insure that the M/F is capital so i added upper function

```
SELECT Name,
    UPPER(SUBSTRING(Gender, 1,1))
FROM tableA
```